# Фо па. Насколько оно необходимо?

Tags: заимствования, неологизмы

«Да, были и ошибки, и непоследовательность, и неудачи, и фо па».

Faux pas (ложный шаг, некрасивый поступок, ошибка; у поляков — kompromitacja).
Первое впечатление: на лицо ужасное, словом *фо па* не назвать, в разговоре и на письме не применить. Приживётся ли? Ваше мнение, пожалуйста!

Comment: Что значит "на лицо ужасное, словом фо па не назвать"? Не могу что-то врубиться...

Comment: Его перевод не однозначен, перечень синонимов таков, что без контекста не опознаешь и не соотнесёшь: в приведённой цитате при упомянутых двух какое значение подходит, не угадаешь. Внешность несуразна на редкость,— расчленёнка от рождения, прости Господи, и чтой-то неприличное на язык ко мне просится (В.В.), а ещё ведь и произношения потребует с прононсом. Поблема с переносом при наборе и т.д. до горизонта.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, нет. Комильфо и се ля ви более-менее прижились, но у них давняя история, а сейчас из французского языка ничего и не заимствуется, потому что его давно перешиб английский.

Comment: Из похожих — фальстарт живёт, однако.

Comment: Из французского?

Comment: Из французского только па (из похожих) .

Answer (score 1):

Очень может быть, что и приживется. Сейчас такое время, что нормы языка способен диктовать кто угодно...

Но вся штука в том, что это выражение не новое, оно из тех времен, когда образованные люди в России говорили по-французски лучше, чем по-русски. А сейчас моду диктует английский. Так что не очень верится, что приживется "само по себе"... Должен быть целенаправленный импульс сверху.

Comment: Перед импульсом кавычки вы хотели поставить, наверное?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой да не надо там вообще кавычек. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Выражение faux pas  существует в английском языке как заимствование из французского.

**Перевод с французского:** 1)  неверный шаг; 2) ложный шаг; 3) промах, ошибка.

Нас оставили в темноте, и спускаться пришлось ощупью с такой высоты, рискуя при малейшем faux pas сломить себе любопытную голову.

**Перевод с английского:** бестактность. Лика сначала обиделась, но потом решила не обращать внимание на «фо па».

Но такт - это  "чувство меры в поведении, в поступках", умение не задевать чувства людей [франц. tact от лат. tactus - прикосновение]. А новое слово **более широкого  значения**, это уже и нарушение стиля, и любые другие промахи, неверные решения.

Возможно, судьба "фо па" будет зависеть **от частотности применения**  в современной литературе или в молодежном сленге.